# Telerik WinForms RadChartView selectedPointChanged not firing

Tags: c#, charts, telerik

i'm having a problem with Telerik RadChartView with SelectedPointChanged event.
I've been googling to try sorting this thing out but there's just no quality results.

Here's an example code :

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        radChartView1.SelectedPointChanged += radChartView1_SelectedPointChanged;
    }

    void radChartView1_SelectedPointChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.ChartViewSelectedPointChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("WORKS!");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LineSeries series1 = new LineSeries();
        series1.Spline = true;
        series1.PointSize = new SizeF(15, 15);
        series1.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Label = "val1", Value = 5 });
        series1.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Label = "val2", Value = 1 });
        series1.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Label = "val3", Value = 5 });
        series1.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Label = "val4", Value = 2 });
        series1.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Label = "val5", Value = 8 });

        radChartView1.SelectionMode = ChartSelectionMode.SingleDataPoint;
        ChartSelectionController controller = new ChartSelectionController();
        controller.AllowSelect = true;
        controller.SelectionMode = ChartSelectionMode.SingleDataPoint;
        radChartView1.Controllers.Add(controller);
        radChartView1.SelectionMode = ChartSelectionMode.SingleDataPoint;
        radChartView1.Series.Add(series1);
    }
```

Please help, I'm using C#, .NET 4,5, VS 2013.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is that adding a controller on Load (that happend after Init, cause the handler on SelectedPointChanged to be overwritten. Try the code I sent you and tell me it if works

Comment: Thank for the time, but still doesn't work. Tried it both in init and load but it's still not being triggered

Comment: Well, after whole day spent trying to get this thing to run, i returned to msChart. It turns out that RadChartView doesn't support SelectedPointChanged on line graph ( works flawlessly with pie charts ).

Answer (score 0):

Damn if I had Telerik I could figure it out fast...

Try to raise the event manually, so we can check if it's the handle that doesn't work or if it's the chart that doesn't rise events. 
To rise the event put somewhere a button and on clicking the button first thing show a message like you are doing for the event, than Rise the event. SHould be something like this (I can't tell the exact syntax, try to figure it out with visual studio help):

```
 MessageBox.Show("BUTTON WORKS!");

Raise new (this, new SelectedPointChanged(this,ChartViewSelectedPointChangedEventArgs(something)));
```

Comment: Tried it, doesn't trigger it :-(